# Are ampersands not allowed in php if-statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

This is how my if-statement starts:

```
<?php if ( bbp_get_forum_title() == 'Business & Finance' ) : ?>
```

If I write just 'Business' it works as expected.
But I now that I placed an ampersand the statement doesn't work any more
(the output is not being echoed).

Any suggestions to fix this?

**EDIT:**

This is the source code:

```
<li id="customwidget-3" class="widget-container widget_customwidget">             <h3 class="widget-title">Sponsored</h3>

Business &#038; Finance              
</li>
```

But if I check the code with firebug I get an `&amp;`.

Comment: Basic debugging first: What does `bbp_get_forum_title()` contain when you are in "Business & Finance"? My bet is the Ampersand is a `&amp;` HTML entity

Comment: @Pekka if I echo it, it outputs: 'Business & Finance'

Comment: @alexchenco: Does it actually? Are you using "View Source" in your browser to check that?

Comment: @alexchenco type CTRL+U to see the HTML source code, and show us the complete code snippet

Comment: @J. Bruni OK I added it in **EDIT** above. And now works (but I've never seen that code for ampersands before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if

```
<?php if ( bbp_get_forum_title() == 'Business & Finance' ) : ?>
```

Doesn't work try:

```
<?php if ( bbp_get_forum_title() == 'Business &amp; Finance' ) : ?>
```

if that doesn't work try:

```
<?php if ( bbp_get_forum_title() == 'Business &#038; Finance' ) : ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

it is possible that your title contains an HTML encoded ampersand entity (`&amp;`), rather than a plain ampersand character. This would be why it doesn't match, even though it looks correct when viewed in the browser.

To confirm this, try viewing the HTML source code for your title to see what the actual string is, rather than simply relying on how it looks in the browser.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey you are right, the output has an `&amp;` (and a lot of extra space). I tried adding `&amp;` to the if-statement but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a string, like in your example, ampersands are allowed in php if statements. The error is elsewhere.

As others pointed, probably `&amp;` is not matching `&` and that's why the result is different from what you expected.